# How send SMS or Email verification automatically in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I send for example SMS code verification in Flutter (without Firebase Auth because I have MySQL database with PHP connection).

I have tried :

```
Future<void> _sendCode(String phoneNumber) async
  {
    phoneNumber = "XX XX XX XX XX";
    String code = _createCode();
    String message = "The code is $code";

    String uri = 'sms:$phoneNumber?body=$message';
    await launchUrlString(uri);
    
  }
```

And many other things, but it open messaging on my device. **I want the code to be sent automatically**.

I have tried to find out how to send a message from PHP but without satisfactory result.

Comment: You can't force sending an SMS. Even though it's increasingly more common that people have unlimited free SMS, it's definitely not true for everyone. If what you want would be possible you could force people to spend their real money. That would be really bad

Comment: I see you are right. But how do the apps in the PlayStore send verification messages?

Answer (score 0):

You can try flutter_otp package I think it's the best option,

You can visit https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_otp for more info,

Comment: That package is a joke. It will send the OTP *from the users device*. All the user needs to do is check their *sent* messages and they will have the OTP. It's basically faking an OTP to make the app look secure without adding even a bit of security.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher/example) package.